# what is the nodejs package for s3 image upload

Tags: node.js, image, amazon-s3

I'm looking to upload my assets to s3.
Is there any package in Nodejs like [carrierwave in rails](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)

I want to resize images with versions.
I have come across [papercut](https://github.com/Rafe/papercut).

What is the best node module for s3 image upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [s3-uploader](https://github.com/Turistforeningen/node-s3-uploader), it's flexible and efficient resize, rename, and upload images to Amazon S3.

Comment: Yes, the author very active, you can contact him via Gitter. It's recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [knox](https://github.com/Automattic/knox) module by Automattic would be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [streaming-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streaming-s3). It has a very good performance with both images and video.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from the below site.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-s3-utils